# Mongo query different attributes on different rows

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection with the fields
visit_id, user_id, date, action 1, action 2

```
example:
1 u100 2012-01-01 phone-call -
2 u100 2012-01-02 - computer-check
```

Can I get in mongodb the user that has made both a phone-call and a computer-check no matter the time ? ( basically it's an AND on different rows )

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible without map/reduce work.

I see it can be done in following way:

1.First you need run map/reduce that produce to you results like this:

```
{
 _id : "u100",
 value: {
   actions: [
       "phone-call",
       "computer-check",
       "etc..."
  ]
 }
}
```

2.Then you can query above m/r result via [elemMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with a single query-- if this is something you're doing frequently in your application I wouldn't recommend map/reduce-- I'd recommend doing a query in mongodb using the $or operator, and then processing it on the client to get a unique set of user_id's.

For example:

```
db.users.find({$or:[{"action 1":"phone-call"}, {"action 2":"computer-check"}]})
```

In the future, you should save your data in a different format like the one suggested above by Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [MongoDB `group` method](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group) that can be used for your query, comparable to an SQL `group by` operator.

I haven't tested this, but your query could look something similar to:

```
var results = db.coll.group({
    key: { user_id: true },
    cond: { $or: [ { action1: "phone-call" }, { action2: "computer-check" } ] },
    initial: { actionFlags: 0 },
    reduce: function(obj, prev) {
        if(obj.action1 == "phone-call") { prev.actionFlags |= 1; }
        if(obj.action2 == "computer-check") { prev.actionFlags |= 2; }
    },
    finalize: function(doc) {
        if(doc.actionFlags == 3) { return doc; }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Again, I haven't tested this, it's based on my reading of the documentation. You're grouping by the `user_id` (the `key` declaration). The rows you want to let through have either `action1 == "phone-call"` or `action2 == "computer-check"` (the `cond` declaration). The initial state when you start checking a particular `user_id` is 0 (`initial`). For each row you check if `action1 == "phone-call"` and set its flag, and check `action2 == "computer-check"` and set it's flag (the `reduce` function). Once you've marked the row types, you check to make sure both flags are set. If so, keep the object, otherwise eliminate it (the `finalize` function).

That last part is the only part I'm unsure of, since the documentation doesn't explicitly state that you can knock out records in the `finalize` function. It will probably take me more time to get some test data set up to see than it would for you to see if the example above works.